# Advanced Post-process CSS: group "media query" and "equal rules", remove "unused properties"

Tags: css, post-processor

I'm looking for a "*CSS Post-processor*" that will optimize a CSS file.

For example, I know that that are tool that minimize .css files but I would like something that go further in this optimization. Here are some example of possible criteria:

**1) Group media-query**:

If I have multiple instances of the same mediaquery, this tool should group all selectors under only one instance

**2) Group equal rules**:

If I have these rules:

```
.foo1
{
  color:red;
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}

.foo2
{
  color:blue;
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

They should grouped into the following final CSS:

```
.foo1,
.foo2
{
  color:red;      
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}

.foo2
{
  color:blue;
}
```

**3) Remove unused properties**:

If I have these properties:

```
.foo1
{
  color:red;      
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}

.foo1
{
  color:blue;
}
```

It's clear that with this declaration order `.foo1` will never have `color:red` applied, and so it should be "condensed" in:

```
.foo1
{
  color:blue;      
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [http://cssminifier.com/](http://cssminifier.com/)?  It appears to meet all your criteria.

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard well it seems very similar to what I'm looking for. Please, convert your comment into a detailed answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://cssminifier.com/.

### It groups media-queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    html {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
@media screen and (max-width:300px){body,html{background-color:#add8e6}}
```

### It groups equal CSS stanzas:

```
.foo1
{
  color:red;
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}

.foo2
{
  color:blue;
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Becomes:

```
.foo1,.foo2{border:1px solid green;font-size:13px;text-align:center}.foo1{color:red}.foo2{color:#00f}
```

### It removes overridden CSS rules:

```
.foo1
{
  color:red;      
  border:solid 1px green;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align:center;
}

.foo1
{
  color:blue;
}
```

Becomes:

```
.foo1{border:1px solid green;font-size:13px;text-align:center;color:#00f}
```

Of course, you may want to beautify your CSS code after minimizing it.  If so, run it through a CSS formatter such as http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/.

---

**UPDATE By Question author**:

Actually, CSSMinifier has a specific case in which minification is not perfect. Look at the following code:

```
.a { color:red;}
.b { color:red;}

.c { color:green;}
.c { color:green;}
.b { color:red;}
```

Is minimized into:

```
.a{color:red}
.c{color:green}
.b{color:red}
```

CSSMinifier, correctly understood that two declarations on `.c` class are equals so, second one can be skipped, but second `.b { color:red;}` **after**
.c { color:green;} breaks default behaviour in which

```
.a { color:red;}
.b { color:red;}
```

is minified in:

```
.a,.b{color:red}
```

Not a grave issue, but it exists.